# Dynamic Sitemap script submit webmaster tool?

Tags: php, sitemap, google-search-console

I’ve created a dynamic `sitemap.php` script to create `sitemap.xml` for Google’s webmaster tools. How can I schedule it to run the script every day? When I upload the sitemap in webmaster tools, is it possible to run that script daily?

Answer (score 1):

If you host supports is you can setup a CRON job to run sitemap.php once a day.

Google will searching your sitemap.xml as much as it wants to. As long as you setup a CRON job that is running your sitemap.php daily anytime google access your sitemap.xml it should be up to date (with in 24hrs).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options
1) Create sitemap.php so that it echos sitemap XML and create rewrite rule through .htaccess so that sitemap.xml is mapped with sitemap.php and then you can submit url www.website.com/sitemap.xml to Google

This option will have google capture new links automatically, no need to automate script.

2) Other option is to have sitemap.php creating separate file sitemap.xml and you can submit same url www.website.com/sitemap.xml

In this option you need to schedule your sitemap.php file to run periodically using crontab. You can learn more about crontab [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_crontab.htm)

---

But don't submit www.website.com/sitemap.php to google, it will not work AFAIK.